# How to create a flutter camera with mask and framing (automatic)?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, imagepicker, image-cropper

Please help me create a flutter camera app with a mask layout. I do not know how to make the camera have a rectangular mask that automatically frames the image after shooting.

At the moment, I'm making an image and then manually cropping it, after which it is saved in the gallery.

*The code looks like this*

***Main.dart***

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:app_math_img/services/image_picker_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';
import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState(_scaffoldKey);
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey;

  _MyHomePageState(this._scaffoldKey);
  XFile? imageFile;
  Future<void> saveImageToGallery() async {
    // Save image to gallery
    await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(imageFile!.path);

    // Show a message to the user
    if (_scaffoldKey.currentContext != null) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(_scaffoldKey.currentContext!).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text('Image saved to Gallery'),
        ),
      );
    }

    // Trigger a rebuild to display the saved image
    setState(() {});
  }

  void _onClick() async {
    imageFile = await ImagePickerService().pickCropImage(
      cropAspectRatio: const CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 16, ratioY: 9),
      imageSource: ImageSource.camera,
    );
    if (imageFile != null) {
      saveImageToGallery();
    }
    setState(() => {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: widget._scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: imageFile != null
            ? Image(image: FileImage(File(imageFile!.path)))
            : const Text('No image selected'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _onClick,
        child: const Icon(Icons.camera),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***image_picker_service.dart***

```
import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class ImagePickerService {
  Future<XFile?> pickCropImage({
    required CropAspectRatio cropAspectRatio,
    required ImageSource imageSource,
  }) async {
    //Pick image
    XFile? pickImage = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: imageSource);
    if (pickImage == null) return null;

    //Crop picked image
    CroppedFile? croppedFile = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
      sourcePath: pickImage.path,
      aspectRatio: cropAspectRatio,
      compressQuality: 90,
      compressFormat: ImageCompressFormat.jpg,
    );
    if (croppedFile == null) return null;

    return XFile(croppedFile.path);
  }
}
```